# Freeing char* data not working

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, free

I have a List, each node in the list holds a char *data field which has to be malloc'd with the node itself, but when I try to free that data the console just stops, it doesn't crash, their is no error, nothing. But if I comment it out and only free the list node it works fine.

Am I doing this right?

```
void removeSpecificData(List *list, char *course)
{
    ListNodePtr currentNode = list->head;
    ListNodePtr previousNode = NULL;

    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(currentNode->data, course) == 0)
        {
            ListNodePtr nodeToFree = currentNode;

            if (previousNode == NULL)
            {
                list->head = currentNode->nextNode;
                currentNode = list->head;
            }
            else
            {
                previousNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode;
                currentNode = previousNode->nextNode;
            }

            printf("Free Data");
            free(nodeToFree->data);
            printf("Free Node");
            free(nodeToFree);
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my createListNode function incase it's necessary to view.

```
ListNodePtr createListNode(char *newCourse)
{
    ListNodePtr newNode = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode->data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(newCourse) + 1));
    strcpy(newNode->data, newCourse);
    newNode->nextNode = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first function shall not compile because the variable nodeToFree is neither declared nor assigned. So this statement  free(nodeToFree); does not make sense.:)

Answer (score 3):

The following line is incorrect.

```
newNode->data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(newCourse) + 1));
```

The `sizeof()` part is not right. If the length of the string is greater than `sizeof(size_t)`, you end up allocating less memory than you need. The call to `strcpy` following it will use memory beyond what you allocated. As a consequence, your program will have undefined behavior.

Use

```
newNode->data = malloc(strlen(newCourse) + 1);
```

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

The allocation size is incorrect. It's detected by the system only when attempting to free the memory (corrupt memory list).

Why not just:

```
newNode->data = strdup(newCourse);
```

it would allocate the proper size (unlike your attempt) and would copy the string at the same time (no need for `malloc` and `strcpy`)

Comment: "Why not" --> High portability precludes using `strdup()`.  `malloc()` and `strcpy()` are both in the the standard C library.  `strdup()` is not.  Yet `strdup()`  is very commonly available - to the point of being ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `removeSpecificData` at least has a typo or a bug because there is absent a declaration of the variable `nodeToFree` and neither value was assigned to the variable.

So this statement

```
free(nodeToFree);
```

does not make sense.

Also in this else block the second expression statement does not make sense.

```
    else
    {
        previousNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode;
        currentNode = previousNode->nextNode;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    }
```

The function is too complicated. It can be written much simpler. For example

```
void removeSpecificData(List *list, const char *course)
{
    ListNodePtr *currentNode = &list->head;

    while ( *currentNode != NULL && strcmp( ( *currentNode )->data, course) != 0 )
    {
        currentNode = &( *currentNode )->nextNode;
    }

    if ( *currentNode != NULL )
    {
        ListNodePtr tmp = *currentNode;
        *currentNode = ( *currentNode )->nextNode;

        free( tmp->data );
        free( tmp );
    }
}
```

As for the function `createListNode` then the expression

```
strlen(newCourse) + 1
```

has the type `size_t`. So the value of the expression that by the way is not evaluated:)

```
sizeof(strlen(newCourse) + 1)
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
sizeof( size_t )
```

and is equal to 4 or 8 depending on the definition of the type `size_t`.

You nedd to write just

```
newNode->data = (char *)malloc( strlen(newCourse) + 1 );
```

Comment: nodeToFree is declared closest to its first use, inside the if statement when the course is found, the change to mallocing fixed the issue though, thank you. :)